# Call baseclass property

Tags: vb.net, oop, properties

It's rather a simple question and both will work. But I'm just wondering what the best practice is. When a child class changes a variable in the baseclass. Should it call the property or just change the underlying variable.

I'm not using the property to do something with the data. The code in the child class is the same. But what is considered the best practice OOP wise?

Sample code:

```
Public Class TestDirect
    Protected temp As Integer

End Class

Public Class TestChldDirect
    Inherits TestDirect

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.temp = 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

versus

```
Public Class TestProperty
    Private _temp As Integer
    '
    Public Property temp() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._temp
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me._temp = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class TestChldProperty
    Inherits TestProperty

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.temp = 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What's wrong with public properties that you set directly?

Comment: I tend to mix them, despite the fact that using a property does allow flexibilty later on.

Comment: What exactly do you by flexible? Now they are here later they are gone?

Comment: Well if you start from the beginning with properties instead of direct editing. You can call other functions in the set/get part of the property. If you start with direct editing, you will have to convert it to a property later on. Not that much work but worth considering I think

Comment: Whilst best practice would definitely point you towards method 2 (hiding your implementation etc) there is also an argument that you shouldn't write code now on the off chance that you might need it later on. There are some subtle differences though: 1. Changing a field to a property is a breaking change  (ie. although calling code stays the same any calling code will need to be recompiled - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/04/11/572694.aspx) 2. Reflection differentiates between fields and properties so might give you problems if you use it.

Comment: This question makes little sense. What is this direct editing you speak of? A class is an object, the properties give it some depth and character. Subs do work and Functions return values. External properties are Public where Fields should be Private. This is basic principles of class definition and OOP.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach gives you more flexibility later on and better protects/hides your underlying implementation. For instance, in your example you might want to modify the type of temp, add some validation etc. Those changes would be more difficult in your first example as you would be affecting the classes that derive from your base class. In the second example you can make the change without affecting any derived classes.